# Посчитать в датафрейме сумму значений с конца

Tags: python, dataframe

В датафрейме `df` нужно посчитать сумму всех `count` для `f` и сумму всех `count` для `d` за последние 6 секунд снизу датафрейма. Как это лучше сделать?

```
time  code   count   sec

1      f      10     49
2      f      5      49
3      d      7      51
4      d      2      52
5      f      9      54
6      f      10     54
7      d      5      54
8      f      8      56
```

Результат:

```
5 секунд это 56-6 = 50 - значит до 50-й секунды

d      7      51
d      2      52
f      9      54
f      10     54
d      5      54
f      8      56
```

Результат будет f_count = 27, а для d_count = 14 (допустим результаты выведем в f_count и d_count)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При df:

```
     code  count  sec
time                 
1       f     10   49
2       f      5   49
3       d      7   51
4       d      2   52
5       f      9   54
6       f     10   54
7       d      5   54
8       f      8   56
```

делаем выборку и группируем:

```
res = df.loc[df['sec']>=(df['sec'].iloc[-1]-5)].groupby('code')['count'].sum()
```

res:

```
code
d    14
f    27
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: groupby('code')['count'].sum() вот эта часть строки плохо работает - по времени отсеивает хорошо, но дальше превращает в кашу. Можно ли использовать какой то другой подход в сортировке

Comment: @z4neo наверняка можно, но нужен более показательный пример данных.